# JPA lifecycle hook gets triggered on db queries

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

*BaseEntity.java* (Every entity class extend BaseEntity)

```
@EntityListeners({EntityAuditor.class})
public abstract class BaseEntity {
  ...
}
```

*EntityAuditor.java*

```
class EntityAuditor {
  @PostPersist
  void logEntityCreate(Object entity) {
    ...
  }

  @PostUpdate
  void logEntityUpdate(Object entity) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Now when I'm calling a `findByXyz` on repository (which has @transactional annotation) from my test, it triggers @PostUpdate method. I understand that the JPA is trying to do a DB flush at this moment. But I don't have any db changes prior to that which is not committed to DB. I've verified the db data before and after the trigger. Only timestamp fields and version fields are updated. How do I make sure that the JPA hooks are triggered only if I have something to persist in db?

Comment: If your timestamp changes that is a change that needs to get persisted.

Comment: Where does this change come from if you didn't change anything?

Comment: I could see the findBy method calls postUpdate from the debugger.

Comment: How does the entity in question get into the `EntityManager`?